# Cannot override core ruby class in Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I want to extend the ruby class, for example,

```
# lib/core_ext/hash.rb

class Hash
  def gop_compact
    delete_if{|k, v| (k.blank? || v.blank?)}
  end
end
```

I have created a separate folder in the /lib directory as follows,

`lib/core_ext/hash.rb`

And I tried to include this path in load_paths as follows,

```
# config/environment.rb
config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/core_ext )
```

After all this setup, restarted the server and tried calling method on a Hash object but it throws an undefined method exception.

> Note:- Rails version is 2.3.4

I spent lot of time on this but no luck yet. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you've added the `core_ext` folder to your load paths, you'll still need to require it with `require 'hash'`. To minimize memory usage, Rails won't actually require ruby files just because you add them to your `load_path`.

```
>> Hash.instance_methods.grep(/gop/)
=> []
>> require "hash"
=> true
>> Hash.instance_methods.grep(/gop/)
=> [:gop_compact]
```

Comment: Yes it does work. But how I could make this method available through out the application?

Comment: require in your `environment.rb` right after you add it to your load path.

Comment: I tried `require "hash"` after this line `config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/core_ext )` in `environment.rb` file. It throws exception. Am I misunderstood?

Comment: Is it a `cannot load such file` exception? I'm not too familiar with Rails 2, do you have an `applicaiton.rb` file? If so, require it along with Rails at the top.

Comment: Yes., that's the exception. And it worked requiring in `application.rb` file. Thank you @Anthony